# After importing a table in phpmyadmin, it is not visible on the left side panel

Tags: mysql, import, export

I am importing a table in MySQL, but I don't see the table in the database, yet it says the import was successful. The table was originally exported from a Linux system, and then to a windows setup, does that have anything to do with it?
What could this possibly mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make you have selected the right database (to where you imported) in the left side.

Else, Refresh the PhpMyAdmin Page. You will see the table.

Comment: post your create table script and a screenshot of phpMyadmin